# How do I assign a datasource to report in SSRS using Powershell

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

I have uploaded my RDL files in the SSRS using Powershell. I have also created a new datsource.
How do I assign the datasource to the reports that I have uploaded using Powershell?

A code example will help immensely.

Comment: The datasource reference is in the report's RDL, I assume you are getting an error when trying to run the reports? If so what error do you get? Have you tried opening and running from Visual Studio or Report Builder first?